# Excluding nodes based on three attributes

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I am trying to copy all nodes only once from a document using this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(@id = preceding-sibling::node()/@id and @version = preceding-sibling::node()/@version and @lang = preceding-sibling::node()/@lang)]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, this code makes each node() with the same id be copied only once, regardless of wheter they have the same lang and version or not.

so if the node with id="2" version="2" and lang="en" is above the node with id="2" version="1" and lang="en", it the node with version 1 is not copied.

Why is only one condition evaluated?

Comment: Can you edit your question to show a sample of your XML, and the output you expect in that case? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the expression:

```
node()[not(@id = preceding-sibling::node()/@id and @version = preceding-sibling::node()/@version and @lang = preceding-sibling::node()/@lang)]
```

selects any node that doesn't have a preceding sibling with the same `id`, and doesn't have a preceding sibling with the same `version`, and doesn't have a preceding sibling with the same `lang`.

This is **not** the same thing as a node that doesn't have a preceding sibling with the same combination of `id` and `version` and `lang` (all three in a single node).

I believe using `xsl:for-each-group` would be a much better strategy to deploy here.

Comment: aaah okay... so each condition is checked individually... Thanks a lot!